# Automatic switch to the workspace of the selected app in Ubuntu 20

Tags: gnome, workspace-switcher, dash-to-dock

When I click in the dock the application that is open in the not current workspace, then nothing happens. I would expect gnome to switch workspace where the clicked application is and show this application.

How to enable such behaviour?

Some specs:
I am using Ubuntu LTS and I installed Dash to Dock.

Comment: Works fine for me 20.04.1 LTS without Dash to Dock

Comment: Not normal behaviour. It normally switches automatically to the other workspace. Something may be broken with your system. 1) (Is it the extension?") Disable the extension, reboot and see whether it still happens (i.e., using the Dash in the overview) 2) (Is it a system wide problem or user account only?) If it does, temporarily create a new account and see if it happens there.

Comment: What is the actual version number? 20 is probably not it. 20.04 or 20.10

Comment: @David By LTS I meant 20.04